# Springer svjour3 template has too much space between title and author

Tags: sv-classes, springer

I am going to send my paper to the springer and select the svjour3 two-column template.
But it has too much space between title and author, I want to ask if this is normal, my mentor said that space needed to be solved.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You should always provide sample code for others to test. In general, if you've been asked to use a template, you use it and don't attempt to change the layout even if you don't like it. It will only annoy the editors at the receiving end as they have to spend time undoing what you did.